# How do I hide all running applications in Linux until a password is entered?

Tags: linux, x11, gnome, xorg

I am implementing a 2 person logon implementation in Gnome using kdesu. The 1st person utilizes the gnome-screensaver lock to login, and a background script running the dbus-monitor application triggers kdesu to lock on a second operator.

The issue is kdesu is just a dialog application.  Once the 1st user unlocks the screen, via the gnome-screensaver, the user can just move the kdesu dialog out of the way and keep working on the system.  I can't allow this.  I have to force them to enter their password into kdesu also.

So is there a way I can cover the entire screen size with a blank dialog, modal window, etc. so that the user only has access to is the kdesu dialog?

Comment: Yes, there's a way. But you have to give a bit more first. Are you using a toolkit? Plain Xlib? Also, please note one important thing: the window manager controls window movement, not X. You can take every route possible but, if the window manager doesn't support it, it won't work and the user won't be forced to do anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not coding.  I'm limited to Perl and whatever command line application tools are available(zenity, xwininfo, etc.).

Comment: Then I'd say it's not likely to be possible, unless there's a method I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Try stopping the window manager with `kill -STOP <pid>`, then resuming with `kill -CONT <pid>`. This will probably not work with compositing WMs so you will need to disable compositing, at least temporarily. This is not 100% bulletproof as other applications may be listening to hotkeys. If you want to be absolutely sure, stop all processes except those you know you need for unlocking, then resume when the screen is unlocked.

Comment: How do I disable compositing?

Comment: Your WM probably has a dbus interface to enable and disable compositing. Use a dbus GUI such as `qdbusviewer` to check.

Comment: Have you considering reconfiguring the display manager, I think the display manager uses PAM, PAM is the configurable authentication manager on Gnu/Linux. You can probably configure it to do what you want.